# order the nested group based on date in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

My table looks like this (grouped based on `GrandParent`, `Parent` and `Child`):

```
Child | Parent | GrandParent |       Date
---------------------------------------------------
  2   |    1   |    1        | 2015-11-04 01:30:22 
  3   |    1   |    1        | 2015-11-05 01:30:22 
  4   |    4   |    4        | 2015-11-04 01:31:41 
  5   |    5   |    5        | 2015-11-04 01:31:41 
  7   |    7   |    7        | 2014-08-19 03:45:01 
  88  |    8   |    8        | 2014-08-19 03:45:01 
  90  |    8   |    8        | 2014-08-19 03:45:01 
  97  |    8   |    8        | 2015-03-18 03:45:01 
  704 |    8   |    8        | 2015-03-18 03:45:01 
  27  |   11   |    9        | 2015-10-22 06:42:30 
  28  |   11   |    9        | 2015-10-24 06:42:30 
  30  |   12   |    9        | 2015-11-15 06:42:30 
  31  |   12   |    9        | 2015-11-16 06:42:30
```

`Child` without `Parent` will consider itself as `Parent` and `GrandParent`.

My target is to order the above table such that:

1. `GrandParent` group with recent date should be at top
2. Inside `GrandParent`, `Parent` group with recent date should be at top
3. Inside `Parent`, `Child` with recent date should be at top

The result should be:

```
Child | Parent | GrandParent |       Date
---------------------------------------------------
  31  |   12   |    9        | 2015-11-16 06:42:30 
  30  |   12   |    9        | 2015-11-15 06:42:30
  28  |   11   |    9        | 2015-10-24 06:42:30 
  27  |   11   |    9        | 2015-10-22 06:42:30  
  3   |    1   |    1        | 2015-11-05 01:30:22 
  2   |    1   |    1        | 2015-11-04 01:30:22
  4   |    4   |    4        | 2015-11-04 01:31:41 
  5   |    5   |    5        | 2015-11-04 01:31:41 
  97  |    8   |    8        | 2015-03-18 03:45:01 
  704 |    8   |    8        | 2015-03-18 03:45:01 
  88  |    8   |    8        | 2014-08-19 03:45:01 
  90  |    8   |    8        | 2014-08-19 03:45:01 
  7   |    7   |    7        | 2014-08-19 03:45:01
```

Comment: What is this `2015-11-65` ? Are you sure 7 comes before 8?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri : Thanks for noticing , corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.* from @t t1
join (select grandparent, max(date) as date from @t group by grandparent) t2 
   on t2.grandparent = t1.grandparent
join (select parent, max(date) as date from @t group by parent) t3 
   on t3.parent = t1.parent
order by t2.date desc, t3.date desc, t1.date desc
```

You are joining initial table with 2 sets, where first set represents max dates per `granparent` and second represents max dates per `parents`.

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f304c/4

Comment: Thanks a lot @Giorgi Nakeuri.

Comment: @Karthikeyan, isn't this version the same as in Thorsten's unswer? His vervion is really better.

Comment: I believe this is better in case of performance wise, since the Table I given in example is created by joining multiple table (To obtain the GrandParent,Parent,Child relationship group).

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri: Thank you very much for mentioning my answer. I did some testing with my DBMS, which is Oracle, and found my query to be faster there, too. That may still be different for SQLite of course. I also tried the analytic function MAX OVER (not available in SQLite), which would have been my favorite, but that was horribly slow. Obviously it is sometimes faster to read the table twice instead of sorting and re-sorting it. I'm sure though, it's just a matter of time, till Oracle's optimzer will handle that equally effective.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: I like Giorgi's answer and I don't mind that you have chosen his answer over mine. Joining aggregated data is a good approach,  quite often the best approach to a problem. I'd just like to mention though that performance should not be your first concern when writing SQL. Write your queries straight-forward and easy to read. Only when running into performance issues should you think of re-writing it. (Of course you could argue that you don't consider my query more readable :-) It's just a general advice. Your argument "is better [..] performance wise" made me write this advice.)

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Use subqueries in ORDER BY.

```
select child, parent, grandparent, date
from mytable
order by
  (select max(date) from mytable grp where grp.grandparent = mytable.grandparent) desc,
  (select max(date) from mytable grp where grp.parent = mytable.parent) desc,
  date desc;
```

Comment: Umm, learened something new today. Didn't know that one can use correlated subquery in `ORDER BY` clause. This performs better then my version at least on `Sql Server`.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri: This in turn surprises *me*. I would have thought your query to either use the same execution plan or an even better one than mine :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I believe a slight modification  to above Query will provide an added advantage as provided below == >

select child, parent, grandparent, date
from mytable
order by
  (select max(date) from mytable grp where grp.grandparent = mytable.grandparent) desc,grandparent,
  (select max(date) from mytable grp where grp.parent = mytable.parent) desc,parent,
  date desc;

Comment: @Karthikeyan: No, this cannot be faster, only slower. The first subquery orders by grantparents, so to get 9 first, then 1, 4, etc. Then you say that inside you want to sort by grantparent, but within grantparent 9 all records are grantparent 9 of course. So this doesn't change anything, but only gives the DBMS additional work to do (if it doesn't detect its needlessness and simply skip it).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: In Case If Two GrandParent or Parent  has the same max(Date), which might result  in breaking the Group (GrandParent, Parent,Child). 
Try with "mytable" in given link ==> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: Karthikeyan: Yes, sorry, you are right. If you want same ranked grandparent numbers unmixed, then yes, you need the additional sort criteria.